# IView.Render to convert paths to absolute

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view

I have this code to get the HTML from some PartialView to be emailed.

```
var sw = new StringWriter();
ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "Email/"+partialViewName);
var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
```

The HTML contains a lot of relative paths such as

```
<a href="~/contact">Contact</a>
```

Is there a way to convert all these to absolute paths when rendering the view?

Comment: Not when rendering the view, but after concerting to a string, you could then use a string.Replace to replace the `~` characters with your protocol/host name

Comment: I thought about that too. But all the ~ characters will be gone, they are replaced automatically on render and become like `/contact`

Comment: Should be able to use a regex to match all `href=/xxxx"` and update.

Comment: True, it's just not ideal :)